# Wordpress posts repeating

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, themes

Hey guys I am using the Imbalance2 theme for WordPress and I have created a new loop to deal with a different page as I have got one category directing to a page, however the posts that are on the page when first loaded are just repeating as I scroll down the page. It is using an ajax thing to load on scroll. Below is my code for the new loop:

```
    <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="post-0" class="post error404 not-found">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'imbalance2' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'imbalance2' ); ?></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $imbalance2_theme_options = get_option('imbalance2_theme_options') ?>

<div id="boxes">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="rel">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
    <?php if ($imbalance2_theme_options['images_only'] == 0): ?>

            <h1 style="padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:2px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    <div class="categories" style="padding-top:5px;"><?php
                    $key = 'title';
                    $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
                    if($themeta != '') {
                        echo "<strong>Job Title: </strong>";
                    echo $themeta;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <br />
                    <?php
                    $key = 'location';
                    $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
                    if($themeta != '') {
                        echo "<strong>Location: </strong>";
                    echo $themeta;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>
            <div class="posted"><?php imbalance2_posted_on() ?> <span class="main_separator">/</span>
                <?php echo comments_popup_link( __( 'No comments', 'imbalance2' ), __( 'One Comment', 'imbalance2' ), __( '% Comments', 'imbalance2' ) ); ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif ?>
            <div class="texts">
    <?php if ($imbalance2_theme_options['images_only'] == 1): ?>
                <a class="transparent" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
    <?php endif ?>
                <div class="abs">
    <?php if ($imbalance2_theme_options['images_only'] == 0): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
    <?php endif ?>
<h1 style="padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:2px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    <div class="categories" style="padding-top:5px;"><?php
                    $key = 'title';
                    $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
                    if($themeta != '') {
                        echo "<strong>Job Title:  </strong>";
                    echo $themeta;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <br />
                    <?php
                    $key = 'location';
                    $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
                    if($themeta != '') {
                        echo "<strong>Location:  </strong>";
                    echo $themeta;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    <div class="posted"><?php imbalance2_posted_on() ?> <span class="main_separator">/</span>
                    <?php echo comments_popup_link( __( 'No comments', 'imbalance2' ), __( 'One Comment', 'imbalance2' ), __( '% Comments', 'imbalance2' ) ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
    if ( $imbalance2_theme_options['navigation'] == 0 ) : // Default ?>

<div class="fetch">
    <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Load more posts', 'imbalance2' ) ); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Ajax-fetching "Load more posts"
$('.fetch a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('loading').text('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href') + '#boxes',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(out) {
            result = $(out).find('#boxes .box');
            nextlink = $(out).find('.fetch a').attr('href');
            $('#boxes').append(result).masonry('appended', result);
            $('.fetch a').removeClass('loading').text('Load more posts');
            if (nextlink != undefined) {
                $('.fetch a').attr('href', nextlink);
            } else {
                $('.fetch').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>

    <?php elseif ( $imbalance2_theme_options['navigation'] == 1 ) : // Infinite scroll ?>

<div class="infinitescroll">
    <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Load more posts', 'imbalance2' ) ); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Infinite Scroll
var href = 'first';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#boxes').infinitescroll({
        navSelector : '.infinitescroll',
        nextSelector : '.infinitescroll a',
        itemSelector : '#boxes .box',
        loadingImg : '<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/loading.gif',
        loadingText : 'Loading...',
        donetext : 'No more pages to load.',
        debug : false
    }, function(arrayOfNewElems) {
        $('#boxes').masonry('appended', $(arrayOfNewElems));
        if (href != $('.infinitescroll a').attr('href'))
        {
            href = $('.infinitescroll a').attr('href');
        }
    });
});
</script>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for any help,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you have two `<?php the_excerpt() ?>` inside one loop, on line 54 and 73.

Comment: Had a look at that an tried removing one of them but no luck :(

Comment: Sorry I missed one before .. In total you have three the_excerpt()

Comment: you have on inside this if statment ` <?php if ($imbalance2_theme_options['images_only'] == 0): ?>`... from my understanding of your code you just need one of them ... I am a bit out of time right now so I wasn't able to give your code a thorough look, which means that I might very well be wrong about the above stuff.

Comment: I have a quick question ... how many duplicates of one post does it show before showing a fresh post.